# How to solve Web Server Reverse Proxy Detection vulnerability reported by Nessus

Tags: proxy, nessus

The host to scan is a telecommunication terminal, which has only one network connection via a cat-5 cable directly to a PC, which installs Nessus to scan the terminal. The terminal has no any other network connections.
The CPU on the terminal is a MIPS with Linux kernel version of 3.18.21.
There is a lightweight legacy boa web server running on the terminal.

The Nessus scan report shows the following vulnerability:

> Web Server Reverse Proxy Detection
>
> Synopsis
>
> The remote service is vulnerable to an access control breach.
>
> Description
>
> The remote web server seems to allow any anonymous user to use it as a reverse proxy. This may expose internal services to potential mapping and, henceforth, compromise.
>
> Solution
>
> Disable or restrict access the reverse proxy.

This could be a false positive. But we are passing a security test with some customer. Wheter it is a false positive or not, we need to bypass it, i.e. make some changes to the terminal so that the Nessus would not report such an issue.

Comment: For instance, if this is a server with a direct cable connection, is this accessible from anywhere in the network or just a single machine? What details (not conclusions) does the report give?

Comment: This edit is, indeed, more information, but not what I asked and not enough to understand the context or what Nessus found. Keep going.

Comment: If there is no other network connection and no other party can access it, then it's a dead issue. That should be easily explained to the customer. As for how to ***fix*** the issue so that Nessus stops finding it, we ***still*** do not have enough detail to suggest anything other than what Nessus provides with the finding: "Disable or restrict access the reverse proxy." **Which you have done**. If you want to "disable Boa's reverse proxy", that's a 4-word google search away: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/boa/1.1.1?topic=guide-disabling-http-port-your-boa-deployment

Answer (score 1):

Such reports are worthless without knowing the environment.

1. Is it *really* a vulnerability, or does the tool make a false positive?
2. If it is a vulnerability, can it be exploited?
3. Is there any environment that lessens or mitigates this vulnerability?

Perhaps the detection gets it wrong, or perhaps the device is isolated so that it can't reach any other device? If so, does it matter, or can it be safely ignored? If the network consists of two isolated devices, it can probably be ignored.

So in short, to mitigate, you have to *understand* the vulnerability, how it works and figure out how it can be exploited. Furthermore, you have to understand the product. If you scan your proxy server, you *expect* it to show up as a proxy.

We can't decide what you should do. You should know your network and on that basis decide what to do with a specific vulnerability.

TL;DR: Vulnerability scanners give you a starting point. Then you have to assess the findings. Nessus doesn't do that.

Comment: Old Boa servers have the proxy enabled by default and can't be disabled. So, the finding is likely a true positive.

Comment: @schroeder Interesting; I was not aware of that :)